# How to copy all files from one folder to another folder using C#?

Tags: c#

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class SimpleFileCopy
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string sourcePath = @"C:\Source\";
            string targetPath = @"C:\Files\";

            if (Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
                DirectoryInfo[] listofSubDir=dirinfo.GetDirectories();
                foreach (var item in listofSubDir)
                {
                    var childItem = item.FullName + "\\" + "C1";
                    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(childItem);
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(file);

                    }


                }

                Console.Read();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using system.IO;   public class SimpleFileCopy
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string sourcePath = @"C:\Source\";
            string targetPath = @"C:\Files\";
Above code before using these code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx), there is the following solution. It recursively copies directories over from source to destination.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class DirectoryCopyExample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Copy from the current directory, include subdirectories.
        DirectoryCopy(".", @".\temp", true);
    }

    private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
        }

        // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it. 
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }

        // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
        }

        // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location. 
        if (copySubDirs)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
            {
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to mention that using async methods (especially if not in a console environment) would be useful

Comment: Please expand? You're welcome to post an alternate answer, too! :)

Comment: Its 90% your answer so i think its more helpful to just add an comment : )

Comment: Suggest an edit, and I'll incorporate it in, then?

Comment: perfect just add it :)

Comment: But I don't even know what you mean haha :$